# Printing invisible figures in octave

Tags: octave

I’m having a problem with printing figures in octave when the figure’s visibility is set to false. For example, the following code produces a “panic: segmentation fault” in Octave version 4.2.2:

```
t = 1:10;
fh = figure(“visible”, false);
plot(t,sin(t))
print(“fig.png”)
```

If I run the above code in Octave version 5.2.0, there is no problem. Is this a bug that was fixed in the Octave 5 update? If so, is there a workaround that I can use for Octave 4? I would prefer to use Octave 4 if possible.

Other notes:
I am running this in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and I installed octave 4 using apt.

Comment: It's very easy to install a newer version of Octave using Flatpack: https://flatpak.org -- don't get stuck on Octave 4 just because that's what comes with Ubuntu 16.

Comment: A workaround to try is to change the graphics backend. There's several different ones available in Octave by default, try them all out see which one works best for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you Chris. Changing the graphics framework to gnuplot fixed the problem

Comment: @CrisLuengo The reason I’m not using octave 5 is because the script I’m running relies on a oct file that only works in octave 4 for some reason. When I call that oct file function using octave 5, it prints an error saying “free(): invalid pointer:” followed by a huge memory dump. The same problem happens in octave 5 even with a very minimal oct file. I built octave 5 from source so maybe I didn’t install it properly?

Comment: When you built the oct file, did you use the same compiler (and version) as you used to build Octave?

Comment: oct files are octave version specific. You can not use one built for version 4 with version 5. You need to rebuild it.

Comment: @matzeri I didn’t realize they are version specific. How do you build an oct file for a specific version? I used mkoctfile to build it, but I didn’t specify a version of octave.

Comment: You would compile it exactly the same way you did last time, except this time using 5.2.0 mkoctfile and libraries. Also, building octave itself from source is usually pretty reliable, if not the best way to get octave. Just make sure you use a prefix to install it at a convenient place (e.g. `--prefix=/opt/octave-5.2.0`). So I doubt it's a problem with that, most problems would have been caught at compile time.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks, I will recompile with the correct mkoctfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is, yes. Here is the relevant line from the [v5.1.0 NEWS](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-5.1.html#dependencies):

> Dependencies:
>
> - The GUI requires Qt libraries. The minimum Qt4 version supported is Qt4.8. Qt5 of any version is preferred.
> - The OSMesa library is no longer used. To print invisible figures when using OpenGL graphics, the Qt QOFFSCREENSURFACE feature must be available and you must use the qt graphics toolkit.

Apparently the now deprecated OSMESA dependency and the printing of invisible figures was a [long-standing pain-in-the-butt](https://savannah.gnu.org/search/?Search=Search&words=invisible+figure&type_of_search=bugs&only_group_id=1925&exact=1&max_rows=25#options). Maybe you'll have some luck going through bug comments (e.g. someone says that if you make it visible at least once, it may be possible to print).

But as people have said in the comments, the best thing to do would be to upgrade your octave version, and recompile your mexfiles for the new version.

Comment: Also, just in case you are attempting to print to a 'display-less' environment (e.g. via ssh): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583636/4183191